# How to put validator if image is null or not in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am using below code select the image and then call the `uploadFile()` function to upload image to the firebase storage in flutter application, how should I put validator to check whether the user uploaded the image or not, if not then prompt the user to upload the image

```
Future getImage() async {
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        avatarImageFile = image;
        isLoading = true;

        print("cbadsbjdb");
      });
  }
    uploadFile();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `then` with `await`

Something like this:

```
await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
        .then((image) async {
          if(image!=null && await image.exists()) {
            print("image selected");
            setState(() {
              _image = image;
            });
            //other code
          }
          else {
            print("image not selected");
            //other code
          }
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("Error: "+error.toString());
    });
```

The function calling this method should be `async`